# Getting featured image with PHP and not javascript from wordpress api _embed

Tags: posts, rest-api, wp-api, wp-remote-get

Not having access to the functions file, I can't add the function to add the featured image to the API so I need to use `wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed`.

With javascript I believe it is `._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']['0'].source_url` so I tried with php after using `wp_remote_get`, `$post->_embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0]->source_url` but the error I am getting is :

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: Your question is a PHP question that's better suited at Stack Overflow. And I just wanted to say FYI, you're getting that error because `$post->_embedded` is an object which is an instance of the generic "empty" class in PHP, namely [`stdClass`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting). So you should've instead used `$post->_embedded->{'wp:featuredmedia'}`.

Comment: @SallyCJ good point, I just thought to ask here in the hope that someone else had this issue. Doing as you suggested was spot on and worked perfectly. You should add it as an answer :)

Comment: So I guessed it correctly that you used something like `$post = json_decode( 'JSON string' )` ?  And I actually wondered - why do you need to use `wp_remote_get()` if the code runs on the same site where you're making the REST API request to? I mean, can't you just do a `new WP_Query` and get the featured image (URL) using WordPress functions?

Comment: @SallyCJ I need to use `wp_remote_get` because I am loading posts from another website via the API, so I can't use `WP_Query`.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to cast the objects as arrays. I recently had to do this in a project where I retrieved a list of articles and needed to display the featured image. There may be alternate ways to handle this issue, but I've found it to be reliable. Here is some relevant code from the project.

```
<?php
  foreach ($articles as $index => $article) {
    $article = (array)($article);
    $embedded = (array)$article['_embedded'];
    $featuredMedia = (array) $embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0];
    $mediaDetails = (array) $featuredMedia['media_details'];
    $sizes = (array) $mediaDetails['sizes'];
    $mediumLarge = (array) $sizes['medium_large'];

    $article_content = "
      <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-$count'>
        <a href='" . $article['link'] . "'>"
          . 
          "<img src='" . $mediumLarge['source_url'] .  "'/>".
          "<p>" . $article['title']->rendered . "</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      ";
    echo $article_content;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I used as suggested, `$post->_embedded->{'wp:featuredmedia'}` and that was enough to solve the issue. But it is good to know another method as you have provided.

Comment: @user8463989 glad you got it working :-) believe it or not, I wasn't aware of the `{'string'}` syntax. I'll likely change my project to match as well